# How can do two questions with ng-if

Tags: angularjs

for example ng-if = "condition1 condition2" would be right?
Condition 1 could be true and condition 2 false.

The code I'm using is below.

```
<div flex="40" layout="column" ng-if="expresion1 expresion2" hide-xs>
<div style="background-color:#373f4c; margin:5px;"> 
    <div layout="column" style="background...">
        <md-button .... >
        </md-button>
    </div>
    <ng-include layout="column" src="..."></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: in javascript "logic or" is `ng-if="expresion1 || expresion2"`, "logic and" is `ng-if="expresion1 && expresion2"`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display the div when:

**one or both variables are true** => use OR *( cond1 || cond2)*

```
<div flex="40" layout="column" ng-if="expresion1 || expresion2" hide-xs>
```

**both variables must be true** => use AND *( cond1 && cond2)*

```
<div flex="40" layout="column" ng-if="expresion1 && expresion2" hide-xs>
```

In your specific case, If I understood correctly you might have to use the OR operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.